# Value of calling method is modified

Tags: java, output

In the following code why output is 0 42 42 rather than 0 0 42.

In Java object is not passed by reference so why value of t.x was modified to 42?

```
class Two 
{
   byte x;
}

  class PassO 
{
  public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    PassO p = new PassO();
    p.start();
}

void start() 
{
    Two t = new Two();
    System.out.print(t.x + " ");
    Two t2 = fix(t);
    System.out.println(t.x + " " + t2.x);
}

Two fix(Two tt) 
{
    tt.x = 42;
    return tt;
}
}
```

Comment: `t` and `t2` are references to the same instance of `Two`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because what's being passed around in Java is the value of the pointer to the object. Thus when you do `tt.x=42`, you are changing the original `t.x` to have a value of `42`. And when you `return tt` you are actually returning the same pointer, so infact `t` and `t2` point to the same instance of the object.

Comment: In below code

    void start()
    {
        Integer t = 0;
        System.out.print(t + " ");
        fix(t);
        System.out.println(t+ " " );
    }

    void fix(Integer tt)
    {
        tt = 42;
    }


Here t is an object of Integer class. Why do get output 0 0  in this case?

Comment: @RohitManglik Because you are setting `tt` to a new instance of an `Integer` class (through autoboxing) with the value `42`, thus is no longer points to the previous `t`.

Answer (score 2):

> In Java object is not passed by reference so why value of t is
>   modified to 42?

The value of `t` is not modified to 42. `t.x` is modified to 42.

> Java is always pass-by-value. The difficult thing to understand is
>   that Java passes objects as references and those references are passed
>   by value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is passed by value. The value is the reference. `t` is a pointer to a `new Two()`. You pass the value that `t` is referring too and point to it with `tt`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method fix is not really testing passed by value adherence. If you were really testing for passed by value adherence the method should be something like below:

```
Two fix(Two tt) 
{
    // Create a brand new instance of Two
    Two newTwo = new Two();
    newTwo.x = 42;
    // Assign the new reference to the passed in value.
    tt = newTwo;    
    return tt;
}
```

In your original fix method you are just mutating the passed in object.